# How the input data is split in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark

I'm coming from a Hadoop background, in hadoop if we have an input directory that contains lots of small files, each mapper task picks one file each time and operate on a single file (we can change this behaviour and have each mapper picks more than one file but that's not the default behaviour). I wonder to know how that works in Spark? Does each spark task picks files one by one or..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spark behaves the same way as Hadoop working with HDFS, as in fact Spark uses the same Hadoop InputFormats to read the data from HDFS.

But your statement is wrong. Hadoop will take files one by one only if each of your files is smaller than a block size or if all the files are text and compressed with non-splittable compression (like gzip-compressed CSV files).

So Spark would do the same, for each of the small input files it would create a separate "partition" and the first stage executed over your data would have the same amount of tasks as the amount of input files. This is why for small files it is recommended to use `wholeTextFiles` function as it would create much less partitions